# gandi.net domain registration advice

Tags: dns

If my domain registrar's servers go down, but my DNS is pointed at amazon, does it affect my website? Or does it not matter once the nameservers are pointed to amazon?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registrar is not about servers. If you use amazon for nameservers, you are absolutelly not related to registar servers, and even if the whole Gandi is down, it does not affects you.

The only thing that does matter about registrar is security - for example if someone hacks into Gandi, they can point yor domain to a different, hacker-owned nameservers.

We use Gandi as our registar, use our own nameservers and so far had no problems.

Comment: is there an advantage to running your own name server and not using [Gandi DNS](https://wiki.gandi.net/en/domains/dns)?